# How to populate an id in an array of objects firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, es6-promise

committeeHead is a reference in collection users. I want to populate this id to get the specific data.
tried using Promise.all but I don't completely understand it and it isn't working for me.

```
const getAllCommittees = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const committees = await db.collection("committees").get();
    const committeesArray = [];
    committees.forEach((doc) => {
      committeesArray.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() });
    });
    const committeesWithUsers = await Promise.all(
      committeesArray.map((committee) => {
        const user = db.collection("users").doc(committee.committeeHead).get();
        return {
          committee,
          user,
        };
      })
    );
    res.json(committeesWithUsers);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    next(err);
  }
};
```